# Second main() class does not see variables initialized in first main() class

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, static

I'm developing an application that requires two main() classes, first one for the actual application, and a second one for the JMX connectivity and management. The issue I'm facing is even after ensuring the first main() is executed and initializes the variables, when the second main() runs but does not see those variables and throws null exception.

Application main():

```
public class GatewayCore {

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GatewayCore.class);
private static ThreadedSocketInitiator threadedSocketInitiator;**
private static boolean keepAlive = true;
//private static Thread mqConnectionManager;

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    __init_system();
    __init_jmx();
    __init_mq();
    while(keepAlive) {}
}

private static void __init_system() {
    try {
        logger.debug("__init_system:: loading configuration file 'sessionSettings.txt'");
        SessionSettings sessionSettings = new SessionSettings(new FileInputStream("sessionSettings.txt"));
        logger.info("\n" + sessionSettings);
        MessageStoreFactory messageStoreFactory = new FileStoreFactory(sessionSettings);
        LogFactory logFactory = new FileLogFactory(sessionSettings);
        MessageFactory messageFactory = new DefaultMessageFactory();
        Application sessionManager = new SessionManager();
        threadedSocketInitiator = new ThreadedSocketInitiator(sessionManager, messageStoreFactory, sessionSettings, logFactory, messageFactory);
...
public static ThreadedSocketInitiator getThreadedSocketInitiator() {
    return threadedSocketInitiator; }
```

Secondary main() class, meant to be invoked for JMX-Mbean purpose:

```
public class RemoteCommandLine {

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RemoteCommandLine.class);
private static final String JMX_SERVICE_URL_PREFIX = "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://";
private static final String HOST = "localhost";
private static String PORT = "24365";
private static JMXConnectionInstance jmxConnectionInstance;
private static boolean keepAlive = true;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, MalformedObjectNameException, ConfigError {
    logger.debug(GatewayCore.getThreadedSocketInitiator());
...
```

From command line, I first run:

```
java -classpath etdfix.jar:slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:mina-core-2.0.16.jar:quickfixj-all-2.0.0.jar -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=24365 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false com.scb.etdfix.GatewayCore sessionSettings.txt
```

Wait for the inits to complete, ensuring threadedSocketInitiator has been assigned, then:

```
java -classpath etdfix.jar:slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:mina-core-2.0.16.jar:quickfixj-all-2.0.0.jar com.scb.etdfix.JMX.RemoteCommandLine
```

Which ultimately throws a null pointer exception for the line:

```
logger.debug(GatewayCore.getThreadedSocketInitiator());
```

My plan is to have the first main() initialize the object, then pass to the second main() to do further method calls using the same object (it must be the same instance) when it is manually invoked. Both classes are compiled together into the same JAR. Please advise on how I can get around this issue or anything I can do to debug this further.

In fact, I'm thinking that this may not be possible as when the 2nd main() is invoked, from its POV the first main() isn't initialized. Therefore I should approach this by considering that they are two separate entities.

Comment: Of course it doesn't. Your second main method doesn't call your initialization method. What exactly did you expect?

Comment: Static variables are not shared across JVM's. You need to run both in one JVM (from a third class with a main method, for example) if you want the static variables to be accessible by both classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each process (each `java` command) is *completely* separate, whether they run the same `main()` or not.  This is a feature—the alternative would be to have unrelated parts of the system collide whenever they used a common utility.

That said, nothing stops you from calling `GatewayCore.main()` yourself (with the real command line or whatever other argument list) if you want to reuse its logic.  It might be a good idea, though, to factor out the common code as another function: `main()` has many special responsibilities and programmers do not usually expect it to be called *within* a program.